# How to get sum of selected DataGrid values in a C# WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, sum

I have a C# WPF app, and my goal is to get the sum of selected row values from a DataGrid, and set a textbox with this total. This sum calculation is triggered by an event that detects when the selected items have changed.

[image: DataGrid sum]

The problem is that when I select many rows at once or select all with Ctrl + A, I get unpredictable sum values.

To troubleshoot, I bound the datagrid with 100 rows, each with an amount of 1. I then selected all items with Ctrl + A. The total sum should be 100, but it caps at 7 or 8 units.

[image: Sample DataGrid]

Below is what I have so far. Anyone see the problem?

```
private void DgDailyTransactions_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dgDailyTransactions.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBlock tb = dgDailyTransactions.Columns[1].GetCellContent(dgDailyTransactions.SelectedItems[i]) as TextBlock;

        if (tb != null)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDecimal(tb.Text);
        }
    }
    tbxSelectedDailyTransactionsTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your class looks like this:

```
 public class Sales
    {
       public int Order { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Make a simple method as under:

```
    private void FindAmount()
    {
        decimal totalSum = 0;
        //Add amounts of selected
        if (MyDTGRID.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dgDailyTransactions.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Sales sales = dgDailyTransactions.SelectedItems[i] as Sales;

                decimal amount = sales.Amount;
                totalSum += amount;
            }
        }
        myTextBlock.Text = totalSum.ToString();
    }
```

Simply call the method in your `selectedCellsChanged` Event

```
    private void DgDailyTransactions_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FindAmount();
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: worked, thanks, bolkay. not sure what's wrong with my solution though.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

for the sum method you can do it using linq (if you don't know I strongly advise you to learn linq, very strong tool in C#), also would advise you to use MVVM, will make your code much easier to debug in future :

```
private void dgDailyTransactions_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Sales> myList=dgDailyTransactions.SelectedItems.Cast<Sales>();
        decimal totalSum = 0;
        if (myList.Count() > 0)
        {
            totalSum = myList.Sum(item => item.Amount);
        }
        myTextBlock.Text = totalSum.ToString();
    }
```

in MVVM (if you use it) you would need just that line in Model :

```
private void dgDailyTransactions_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             contexte.SelectedSales= new ObservableCollection<Sales>(dgDailyTransactions.SelectedItems.Cast<Affaire>());
        }
```

then you use formula in your ViewModel in set section of SelectedSales